# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^p \backslash\{ a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n \}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Question:**
>
> Prove that $\mathbb{R}^p \backslash\{ a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n \}$ is open for each $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}^p$.
>
> HINT: To show $\mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{a \}$ is open, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{a \}$ and choose $r= \frac{1}{2}||x-a||$

**My attempt so far:**

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{a \}$ and $r>0$, $B(x,r) \in \mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{ a \}$ when $r= \frac{1}{2}||x-a||$.

Thus there always exists a neighborhood around $x \in \mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{ a \}$ which is contained in $\mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{ a \}$. Hence $\mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{a\}$ is open.

We now have that $A = \mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{ a \}$ and $A = A^0$. Thus $B(x,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^P \backslash \{a\}$

Can someone please tell me if I am on the right track or point me in the right direction? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb R^p\setminus \{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n \}=\left(\mathbb R^p\setminus \{a_1\}\right)\cap \ldots \cap\left(\mathbb R^p\setminus \{a_n\}\right)$.

Comment: You are on right track. To finalise it you can either use @GitGud hint, or you can to set $r = \min_{j=1,\ldots,n}{||x-a_j||}$ and use the same trick.

Comment: wouldn't be easier if you focus on $(\mathbb{R}_p$$\backslash$$a)^c$? A point is a closed set. And so on..

Comment: another trick is $f(x)=\prod |x-a_i|$, what is $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$